# Display JSON info in a PHP table

Tags: php, html, json, parsing, html-table

I am trying to display JSON content in a PHP table but its not working. I  can't figure out what I should  change.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Download</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$myData = file_get_contents("https://youtubetoany.com/@api/json/videostreams/VEou0QBeHlk");
$myObject = json_decode($myData);
$myObjectMap = $myObject->vidInfo;
?>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
        <td>Url</td>
        <td>Size</td>
        <td>Quality</td>
        <td>Type</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php foreach($myObjectMap as $key => $item): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->dloadUrl; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->rSize; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->round; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->quality; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->ftype; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what I get in my browser:

> Url   Size    Quality     Type

Comment: That URL returns incorrectly formatted string and is not compatible with JSON. Use Application such as Postman check the content and it throw `Syntax error`. Postman

Comment: you could try to cut everything after the (and including) the first `<script` before `json_decoding`. But this source seems not to be made to be grabbed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source has some javascript attached. You need to get rid of that:

```
$myData = file_get_contents("https://youtubetoany.com/@api/json/videostreams/VEou0QBeHlk");

// get the substring from start til the first occurence of "<script"
$myRealData = substr($myData,0,strpos($myData,"<script"));
$myObject = json_decode($myRealData);
```

*BUT* this source doesn't seem to be made to be grabbed. So I won't rely on that source or that it'll stay the way you find it now.

Answer (score 1):

I just found probably why its not working. The link returns a JavaScript attached to the bottom of the JSON. So here is my solution.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Download</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$myData = file_get_contents("https://youtubetoany.com/@api/json/videostreams/VEou0QBeHlk");

// This up to the last occurrence of the "}"
$json_block = substr($myData, 0, strripos($myData, "}"));

$myObject = json_decode($json_block);
$myObjectMap = $myObject->vidInfo;
?>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
        <td>Url</td>
        <td>Size</td>
        <td>Quality</td>
        <td>Type</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php foreach($myObjectMap as $key => $item): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->dloadUrl; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->rSize; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->round; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->quality; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->ftype; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is a `}` right at the end of the stream: `),0,{}));`. So I doubt this will succeed.

Comment: better search for the first `<script`

Comment: @Jeff I was going to do that, but in case the original file no longer has `script` tags, that might throw errors. This in much safer solution. Plus `strripos` use the last occurrence on the file. Only problem would be if there&amp;#39;s a `}` with in the script. In that case your way is better or regex might come in to play

Comment: any version is unrelyable with this source, you're right... The chance to have a `}` in javascript is quite high though...